# Непонятный механизм предоставления помощи в stackoverflow на русском с редиректом в мету!

Tags: поддержка

Маленькое предусловие:
у меня возник вопрос, я его не нашел на сайте (stackoverflow на русском). Далее я его создал. Далее его админы перевели в мету и сказали, что вопрос дублирующийся - мне кажется, что где-то здесь Косяк - как я должен был про мету то узнать??

У меня небольшой опыт на на этом ресурсе. И все же очень хочу понять как кто видит ситуацию с возникновением вопросов по ресурсу stackoverflow находясь на этом ресурсе. Куда он должен задать вопрос/залезть, чтобы найти ответ.

Comment: На форме нового вопроса, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, в блоке справа прямо сказано: Если ваш вопрос о самом сайте, пожалуйста, задайте его на Мете.

Comment: Ну вот узнали, Вас же не ругают за это =)

Comment: Stranger in the Q - Не понятно за что меня должны ругать !  "За  косвенную помощь в устранении ошибок UX сайта ? "
Предлагаю  отредактировать  как в   ответе на скрине ниже красным полем. Либо перенести это на главную страницу в поле поиска вопроса в виде  раскрывающегося списка при результатах поиска -  Ноль  результатов.

Comment: Аргумент :  Когда пользователь не нашел ответ и его целью теперь является задать вопрос, чтобы получить хоть какой-то ответ. Он не смотрит по сторонам во время формулировании вопроса в письме, а пишет его в форме которую формулирует(другими словами он погружён в процесс).  Мне кажется не верным размещение данной подсказки во вложенной форме задания вопроса, да еще и где-то в углу мелким текстом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Там справа написано:

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Вопрос ТСа и означает, что юзабилити плашки справа хромает, и читают её только маньяки.

Comment: Отлично!!!!!   Предлагаю поставить вот такое красное выделение как на картинке   -- в виде  ориентира чтоб хоть как то заметно было. Хотя тоже не факт что прокатит  :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96241/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy------stac).